# ifelse(length(date)==1, date, otherdate) differs between base R, dplyr and data.table

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, null, data.table

I am trying to test if elements of a date vector are of length 0.

this works fine using base R, but returns POSIXct as numeric:

```
a<-numeric(0)

>ifelse(length(a)==1,a,as.POSIXct("2017-12-26 17:53:53 AEDT"))
[1] 1514271233
```

a solution to keep the class is to use dplyr or data.table, but they both return errors:

```
>dplyr::if_else(length(a)==1,a,as.POSIXct("2017-12-26 17:53:53 AEDT"))
Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 0
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

>data.table::fifelse(length(a)==1,a,as.POSIXct("2017-12-26 17:53:53 AEDT"))
Error in data.table::fifelse(length(a) == 1, a, as.POSIXct("2017-12-26 17:53:53 AEDT")) : 
  'yes' has different class than 'no'. Please make sure that both arguments have the same class.
```

why is it different? I thought these functions would just ignore the `TRUE` option when the logical test returns `FALSE`. Is there a solution that doesn't involve converting back to POSIXct?

Comment: *"test if elements of a date vector are of length 0"*... that doesn't make sense. An element of a vector has length one. If you want to test if a single object has length or not, use `if() {} else{}`, not `ifelse` / `if_else` / `fifelse` / which are intended to act on vectors and return a result of the same length as the input.

Comment: you can try `.POSIXct(a)` or `as.double(as.POSIXct(.))` to get the issue to go away for `data.table`. We made a tradeoff for efficiency to require type consistency in `yes`/`no` arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the good old fashioned way?

```
if(length(a)==1){a}else(as.POSIXct("2017-12-26 17:53:53 AEDT"))
[1] "2017-12-26 17:53:53 EST"
```